# Магия JavaScript(jQuery) для нуба. Объясните?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

При клике на див (внутри инпут), идёт добавление класса `.after`, где он анимирует абс.поз. линию с 0 к 100% ширины. Разумеется при клике на другой див, с другим индексом, у ранее кликнутого должен убраться класс. Вроде бы все просто. Пишу переменную `var temp;`, вне области видимости обработчика, и в конце ей присваивается кликнутый див, при след. клике проверка всегда будет удалять класс у предыдущего. Но магия в том, что я догадался("умно звучит") зарание определить "назначение" переменной, только так это работает. Почему ? Спасибо.

```
var temp = $('.address-section > div:nth-child(1)');

$('.address-section > div').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
var item = $('.address-section > div:nth-child('+ index + ')');

if(temp.hasClass('after')){
    temp.removeClass('after');
}

    item.addClass('after');

temp = item;
});
```

Comment: Судя по описанию, вам вообще не клик надо отслеживать, а `focus/blur` инпута.

Comment: Да, забыл, только последнее поле - textarea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то должно быть что-то типа:

```js
$(function () {
  var $inputs = $('.address-section > div > input');
  
  $inputs.on('focus blur', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('after', e.type === 'focus');
  });
});
```

```css
.address-section div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.address-section div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 0;
  background-color: green;
  transition: max-width .3s;
}

.address-section div.after::after {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="address-section">
  <div><input/></div>
  <div><input/></div>
  <div><input/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Верно, спасибо, только у меня там еще textarea, спасибо за событие фокуса, забыл совсем.

Comment: @Predaytor, ну, тут главное концепция, а не само решение.

Answer (score 2):

Можете не назначать. Тогда это надо учитывать при обращении к `temp`.

```
var temp;

...

  if (temp) {
    temp.removeClass('after');
  } 
...
```

Или вообще без `temp`:

```
  $('.address-section > div.after').removeClass('after');
```

---

И мне непонятны эти манипуляции с индексом. Разве это не то же самое?

```
var item = $(this);
```

Comment: я ведь нуб, спасибо.

Comment: @Predaytor Пожалуйста. Не забудьте принять ответ MedvedevDev - "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: Прошу прощения.